# Data driven subscription for email

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have one scenario where I have to send data which customer handling
there own area in excel not other areas data in Data-driven
subscription(DDS).

```
ID  Name    Data(rows)   email 
1   A        10        A@gmail.com 
2   B        4         B@gmail.com 
3   A        6        A@gmail.com
4   B        5         B@gmail.com 
5   C        4        C@gmail.com
```

In the above example IF DDS is configured for A, it should go 16
   records and for B, It should go 9 records. For C, It will be 4
   records. But for me, it was going all records. Can anyone tell me

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `SUM` and `group by`

```
CREATE TABLE t(
   Name VARCHAR(50),
   Data INT,
   email VARCHAR(50)
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES ('A',10,'A@gmail.com'); 
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('B',4 ,'B@gmail.com'); 
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('A',6 ,'A@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('B',5 ,'B@gmail.com'); 
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('C',4 ,'C@gmail.com');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Name,SUM(Data) records 
FROM T
GROUP BY Name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dbcc1/2/0)**:

```
| Name | records |
|------|---------|
|    A |      16 |
|    B |       9 |
|    C |       4 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query: using group by

```
select name, email, sum(data) as records from tablename
group by name, email
```